# click event listener fires immediately

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, gsap

I have a class that handle the Education section of my web page:

```
class Education{
  constructor(){
    this.courses = [
      {id:'css-course',state:'70'},
      {id:'vue-course',state:'85'},
      {id:'text-mining-course',state:'50'}
    ];
    this.eduButton = document.getElementById('edu-button');
    this.init()
  }

  init(){
    this._initEducation()
  }

  _initEducation(){
    let self = this;
      this.eduButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
        self._initTimeline().play();
      })
      this.eduButton.previousElementSibling.addEventListener('click',function(){
        self.courses.forEach(function(course){
          document.getElementById(course.id).style.width = '0%'
        })
      })
  }
  _initTimeline(){
    const courseTimeline = new TimelineLite();
    this.courses.forEach(function(course){
      let curr = document.getElementById(course.id)
      courseTimeline.to(curr,.3,{width:`${course.state}%`},'width')
    })
    return courseTimeline
  }
}

module.exports = {
  Education
}
```

the _initEducation method is quite similar to another method that i have in the About section, both of them serve to animate a list of progress bar with gsap:

_initAbout:

```
_initAbout(){
    let self = this;
    this.aboutButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
      self._initTimeline().play();
      })
    this.aboutButton.previousElementSibling.addEventListener('click',function(){
      self.skills.forEach(function(skill){
        document.getElementById(skill.id).style.width = '0%'
      })
    })
  }
```

Because this two methods are similar, i wrote an utility class named InitProgressBarAnimation:

```
class InitProgressBarAnimation{
  init(){
    return{
      start:this._start,
      reset:this._reset
    }
  }
  _start(button,timeline){
      button.addEventListener('click',function(){
        console.log(timeline)
        timeline.play()
      })
  }
  _reset(button,data){
    button.previousElementSibling.addEventListener('click',function(){
      console.log('reset')
      data.forEach(function(d){
        document.getElementById(d.id).style.width = '0%'
      })
    })
  }
}
```

and replace, for testing the initEducation method with this:

```
class Education{
  constructor(ProgressBarAnimationHandler){
    ...
    this.ProgressBarAnimationHandler = ProgressBarAnimationHandler;
    this.init()
  }

  _initEducation(){

 this.ProgressBarAnimationHandler.start(this.eduButton,this._initTimeline());
 this.ProgressBarAnimationHandler.reset(this.eduButton,this.courses);
        /*
        let self = this;
          this.eduButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
            self._initTimeline().play();
          })
          this.eduButton.previousElementSibling.addEventListener('click',function(){
            self.courses.forEach(function(course){
              document.getElementById(course.id).style.width = '0%'
            })
          })
          */
      }
```

Now seems that when i load the page, the timeline start doing his job (i can see the style witdh attribute fill itself with the value), and if i close the section the reset function works but then the start function doesn't start again. How that possible? it is a problem with gsap? 
the start method only attach an handler to the button...

Comment: ok seems i solved, in the start method i put instead of this._initTimeline(), this._initTimeline.bind(this), seems works now, someone can tell me if this is a correct solution? thanks!

Comment: Your solution seems right. `_initTimeline()` will immediately invoke the function, whereas `_initTimeline.bind(this)` will set the `_initTimeline` function as the callback of the click handler with the `this` context manually bound to `this` at the time `.bind()` was called.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "()" from _initTimeline. The () tell the function to execute. If you leave them off you are just passing the function to the event handler to execute. This is the standard pattern for what you are trying to do. Finally it would look like this:

```
this.ProgressBarAnimationHandler.start(this.eduButton,this._initTimeline);
```

Comment: i tried removing the bracket, but i get the error 'this is undefined', with passing this._initTimeline.bind(this) to start seems i solved

Comment: Ah I see your issue. Yeah "this" will change depending on the scope where it is called. So in this case "this" is being passed into ProgressBarAnimation where it looks for this._initTimeline which doesn't exist in that object. To do it without bind you would have to pass a reference to Education object. Anyhow sounds like you found another way.